# Programming Game of Life in Android, crashes when attempting to create new generation

Tags: java, android, conways-game-of-life

I am attempting to program Conway's Game of Life as an android app. I have created my initial grid on which I can draw, and have designed an engine. However when I attempt to use my initial grid as input and run the engine the app crashes. The code for the engine is below, I would appreciate if someone could point me in the direction of how to create a working engine.

The primary error that I see is "thread exiting with uncaught exception"

**LifeEngine.java**

```
public class LifeEngine {

    private Context context; 
    private NeighborCheck checker; 
    private MyGridView myGridView; 
    private int height = this.myGridView.getMyHeight();
    private int width = this.myGridView.getMyWidth();

    public LifeEngine(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public char[][] generateNextGeneration(char[][] world) {

        //char[][] currentGeneration = world;
        int neighbors; 
        char[][] nextGeneration = new char[this.myGridView.getMyHeight()][this.myGridView.getMyWidth()];

        for (int c = 0; c < height/UpdateGridActivity.cell_size; c++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < width/UpdateGridActivity.cell_size; r++) {
                if(world[c][r] != 0) //handles live cells 
                {
                    neighbors = checker.check(world,r, c);
                    if (neighbors !=3 && neighbors !=2) 
                        nextGeneration[c][r] = 0; 
                    else
                        nextGeneration[c][r] = '*'; 
                }
                else //handles dead cells
                {
                    neighbors = checker.check(world,r, c);
                    if(neighbors == 3)
                        nextGeneration[c][r] = '*';
                    else
                        nextGeneration[c][r] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return nextGeneration;
    }    
}
```

**NeighborCheck.java**

```
public class NeighborCheck {

    private MyGridView myGridView;

    public int Check(char[][] array, int r, int c)  
    { 
        int neighbor_total = 0;
        int height = this.myGridView.getMyHeight();
        int width = this.myGridView.getMyWidth();

            //top left
            try{
            if (r != 0 && c != 0)
                if(array[r-1][c-1] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

            //top center
            try{
            if (c != 0)
                if(array[r-1][c] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

            //top right
            try{
            if (r != width && c != 0)
                if(array[r-1][c+1] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

            //middle left
            try{
            if (r != 0)
                if(array[r][c-1] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

            //middle right
            try{
            if (r != width - 1)
                if(array[r][c+1] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

            //bottom left
            try{            
            if (r != 0 && c != height - 1)
                if(array[r+1][c-1] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

            //bottom middle
            try{
            if (c != height - 1)
                if(array[r+1][c] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

            //bottom right
            try{
            if (r != width - 1 && c != height - 1)
                if(array[r+1][c+1] != 0)
                    neighbor_total +=1;}
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

        return neighbor_total; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: also, you call checker.check(world,c, r) with world, column, row, but the function parameter takes world, row, column, a huge problem.

Comment: The error message is threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception. It also says NullPointerException further down.

Comment: Also I swithced r and c in the check call.

Comment: well, your null pointer probably comes from the fact that you never initialized your Checker. You declared it at the top, but never instantiated it. You could probably make check() a public static function, that way you can call on to it by saying Checker.check()